# Dynamic span size in GridLayoutManager inside RecyclerView - Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development. I have `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. Each item inside grid is a `CardView` and has different width span and height span. I'm trying to change span inside `onBindViewHolder` but it is not working.

I want to make like this:

[image]

Each item inside `RecyclerView`:

```
public class Tile {
    private String tileName, packageName;
    private Drawable tileImage;
    private int widthSpan, heightSpan;

    Tile(String tileName, String packageName, Drawable tileImage, int widthSpan, int heightSpan) {
        this.tileName = tileName;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.tileImage = tileImage;
        this.widthSpan = widthSpan;
        this.heightSpan = heightSpan;
    }

    public String getTileName() {
        return tileName;
    }
    public void setTileName(String tileName) {
        this.tileName = tileName;
    }

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }
    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public Drawable getTileImage() {
        return tileImage;
    }
    public void setTileImage(Drawable tileImage) {
        this.tileImage = tileImage;
    }

    public int getWidthSpan() {
        return widthSpan;
    }
    public void setWidthSpan(int widthSpan) {
        this.widthSpan = widthSpan;
    }

    public int getHeightSpan() {
        return heightSpan;
    }
    public void setHeightSpan(int heightSpan) {
        this.heightSpan = heightSpan;
    }
}
```

I have tried replacing `GridLayoutManager` with `FlexboxLayoutManager` and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. But nothing is working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain how it is not working?

Comment: Yes, the row span is not changing it is always 1. I want the row span to change for different items in the grid. I also updated the question

Comment: I have updated question